# Block comments in Pug (Jade)?

Tags: pug

How do you block comment out code in the Pug templating engine?

I know how to comment out a line:

```
//-doesn't show
```

but I don't want to have to write in full html comments like so:

```
<!--
    no show
-->
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
//-
    Just indent the comment
    like normal elements
```

Just indent your comment like you do other elements.

Just be careful that you have your indention correct or you may comment out more than you intended.

Comment: But how to comment element attribute?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are wanting to accomplish by commenting attributes. I assume you mean adding comments inside of an HTML tag? If that is the case then this is not supported in HTML or Jade that I'm aware of.

Comment: And the space between the slashes and hyphens also matter

Answer (score 6):

## Official Documentation

https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html#block-comments



**Buffered comments** - *The comment will **appear** in rendered HTML*

```
//
    Comments for your HTML readers.
    Use as much text as you want.
```

**Unbuffered comments** - *The comment will **not appear** in rendered HTML*

```
//-
    Comments for your template writers.
    Use as much text as you want.
```